# Reuse audio player

Tags: trigger.io

Im just playing around with trigger.io, and need some clarification on native component usage. This question is specifically about the audio player, but I assume the other APIs work in the same manner so its probably valid for all APIS.

To play an audio file the documentation states:

```
forge.file.getLocal("music.mp3", function (file) {
   forge.media.createAudioPlayer(file, function (player) {
      player.play();
   });
});
```

If you have multiple audio files that the user can play within the app, with the above code, every time they play a file a new audio player is created. This seems to happen because you can have multiple audio files playing together.

Surely overtime as the person uses the app this is going to consume a lot of memory? There doesnt seem like there is anyway to use an existing player and replace the current audio file with a new one. Is this possible once you have the "player" instance? Or is there a way to dispose the current instance when the user stops the audio or when its finished? or when the user navigates away from that particular audio item?

Thanks
Tyrone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good spot, this is actually just an oversight in our documentation, the player instance has another method `player.destroy()` which will remove the related native instance.

I'll make sure the API docs are updated in the future.